# buying bigger frame to get less aggressive geometry

Tags: road-bike, geometry

If I like a model of bike (looking at giant TCR 2) but the sitting position of the bike is a little too aggressive for my liking i.e. too bent forward instead of upright, is buying a slightly bigger frame and lowering the saddle a good approach to lessen the crouching forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider that as a last resort rather than a first resort, since you can probably accomplish the same effect by getting a shorter stem and/or raising the stem. If you can't change your position enough that way, you might want to consider getting a bike with different geometry.

You can quantify how aggressive a bike's position based on its "stack:reach ratio" (K:L in the diagram below). On the TCR, that number is about 1.4, which is indeed pretty aggressive. Giant has a couple of other models that are a little more upright, the Defy and Contend, where that ratio is about 1.5, which is typical of "endurance bikes."

[image: geometry diagram]

Comment: I didn't know if the stem was adjustable tbh I only have a giant escape 3

Comment: @bakalolo: “Serious” bikes generally don’t come with an adjustable stem. But it’s relatively cheap and easy to exchange it. You can get all kinds of lengths and angles. Most bike shops will be happy to let you try a few. The exception are some recent high-end bikes (e.g. Scott Addict RC) where the stem and handlebars are one unit (which is really stupid from an adjustability standpoint).